# Could not load file or assembly for Oracle with Powershell

Tags: oracle, powershell

I cannot use the OTP .NET leibrary for querying Oracle from Powershell on a Windows server 2012 machine.

I downloaded ODP.NET_Managed_ODAC12cR4.zip and installed with

```
install_odpm.bat c:\oracle x64 false
```

On the server I don't have Oracle installed.

This line:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:/oracle/odp.net/managed/common/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
```

or this line:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:/oracle/odp.net/managed/common/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")
```

both give me the following error:

```
PS C:\temp> .\impoinftel.ps1
Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or
assembly
'file:///C:\oracle\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess33.dll' or
one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
At C:\temp\impoinftel.ps1:2 char:1
+ [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:/oracle/odp.net/managed/common/Orac
le. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

New-Object : Cannot find type
[Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection]: make sure the assembly
containing this type is loaded.
At C:\temp\impoinftel.ps1:4 char:9
+  $con = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User
Id=byb ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewOb
   jectCommand
```

vcredist_x64.exe is installed on my server

powershell.exe.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to unblock this file, so just go to "C:/oracle/odp.net/managed/common/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll", right click it, and select "Properties", under General table, tick the unblock checkbox (at the bottom) and then click Apply then OK buttons.

I encountered exactly the same issue in my Windows 10, and after various attempts, finally solve the issue.